# Create a file between two dockers

Tags: c#, docker

At the moment I have a two containers worked in same time on docker. I would like, my first container run if existed a gif file on disk and collect than.

First Container:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {

        }
        while(!File.Exists("../gif-with-text.gif"));
        // Run Code ...
    }

}
```

Second Container:

```
const TextOnGif = require('text-on-gif');

  let req = 'test';
(async function () {
  let v = `https://media0.giphy.com/media/Ju7l5y9osyymQ/giphy.gif`;

  console.log(`${v}`);
  //create a TextOnGif object
  var gif = new TextOnGif({
    file_path: v,
    //path to local file, url or Buffer
  });


  gif.font_color = 'white';
  gif.font_size = `${25+(2.12*req.length)}px`;
  gif.stroke_color = 'black';
  gif.stroke_width = 5;
  //write as file
  await gif.textOnGif({
    text: `${req}`,
    get_as_buffer: false, //set to false to save time
    write_path: "gif-with-text.gif"
  });

  //res.send(gif);
})();
```

The code of container 1 start if existed file "../gif-with-text.gif", so i needed first started the code of docker 2. My question is how container 1 can detect a new gif file from container 2 (my objective is dont move manualy the file, only automatically!!)??

Comment: you can setup a shared volume between both containers and than just check your mapped directory in the application

Comment: Try to avoid sharing files between containers: it has more moving pieces than you might expect, and doesn't translate well to clustered environments like Kubernetes.  Can you use something like an HTTP POST request, or a message-queueing system like RabbitMQ, to send the data from one container to the other?

Comment: @DavidMaze probably i can... but i dont know how i can do that.